# Connect the flutter with MySQL database with Nodejs API?

Tags: flutter-datatable

I am trying to make connection with flutter with MySQL, Nodejs API. and I did not any idea regarding that, and even there is no any video available on youtube for flutter database connectivity with mysql and node api.

I don't have any idea regarding connectivity with mysql with node, and even there is no any video available on youtube , so I want steps to connect flutter to database with mysql using nodejs.

Comment: Do you know how to build APIs in NodeJS and MySQL ?

Comment: Yes I know but the problem is connectivity with flutter

Comment: Learn about http requests in flutter, build APIs in Node and then connect the flutter app by sending http requests to the NodeJS server

Answer (score 0):

I did not know the exact structure of your app so just share my experience.

It seems that you are tyring to consume something (from a MySQL database) in your Flutter app.

I would do like below:

1. Use PHP and related framework (say Lumen, Slim) to create the API backend and expose it via an URI like: https://api.mydomain.com.
2. In your Flutter or any frontend, use language recommended way to consume the API (which normally returns JSON data) and populate your UI.

Hope that helps.

Comment: And of course, use Node is quite similar to this approach.

Comment: Yeah, but instead of php I want to use nodejs & mysql  for API.